# List models according to ContentType and object_id. (How to List Generic ForeignKey objects)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is `Star` ListAPIView so far I have.

```
[
    {
        "user": 1,
        "content_type": 26,
        "object_id": 7
    },
    {
        "user": 1,
        "content_type": 26,
        "object_id": 8
    },
    {
        "user": 1,
        "content_type": 15,
        "object_id": 5
    },
    {
        "user": 1,
        "content_type": 15,
        "object_id": 6
    }
]
```

Since content_type of the very first object in the array is 26, its referring object is 'Outfit'. For better understanding, I'm providing `Star` Model. It contains ContentType and object_id field. It uses two fields to refer **Generic** foreignKey.

```
class Star(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    objects = StarManager()
```

And here is Serializer and View

serializers.py

```
class ListStarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Star
        fields = ('user', 'content_type', 'object_id')
```

views.py

```
class StarListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ListStarSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Star.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

**Both content_type 26 and 15 have each image fields (called `outfit_img` and `cloth_img`) for each.** To Achieve this, **I want to use different Serializer depending on the content_type**

For example, if content_type is 26, call OutfitListSerializer. If content_type is 15, call ClothListSerializer.

I'm building this `Star` app having help from this link (def create_comment_serializer). (https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Blog-API-with-Django-Rest-Framework/blob/master/src/comments/api/serializers.py).

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you, may be you can use [serializermethodfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)
serializers.py

```
class ListStarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    img_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Star
        fields = ('user', 'content_type', 'object_id')

   def get_img_data(self, obj):
      if obj.content_type_id == 15:
          serializer = ClothListSerializer(obj.content_object)
      elif obj.content_type_id == 26:
          serializer = OutfitListSerializer(obj.content_object)
      else:
          return {}
      return serializer.data
```

Comment: It almost worked But I think we should pass a parameter for both OutfitSerializer and ClothSerializer. Actually the img_data returns `{}`

Comment: Yeah it resolved the error. Not it says `utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`. I'm looking for the solution now :) I guess it's about some weird python error

Comment: Comparing obj.content_type == 15 didn't work so I was comparing it as str(obj.content_type) == 'outfit'. It seemed working

Comment: nvm. maybe it's about image file..?

Comment: outfits/29/None.jpg
Internal Server Error: /stars/list/

Comment: ithink the `utf error ` is raised by file name or something similar, for check content type i think it better to use id, updated the answer

Comment: `outfits/29/None.jpg Internal Server Error: /stars/list/ ` unfortunately don't help to understand your error, i think need more details, model amd serializer and full error stack, better to create new question.

Comment: content_type_id works but it still return internal error. I guess it occured for file name

Comment: somehow str(obj.outfit_img.url) works. Why should I put str in front of it? :) weird

Comment: may be it help [urlfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#urlfield)

Comment: This question can be so easy for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445353/what-can-be-the-filename-of-uploading-location-for-imagefield