# What can be the filename of uploading location for ImageField?

Tags: django, django-models

Whenever I create `Cloth` Model with `cloth_image`, the image uploads to `upload_location`.

My problem is `instance.id` returns `None` because the instance is not yet created. **What can be the best upload_location for ImageField?**

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    new_id = instance.id
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return "clothes/%s/%s.%s" % (instance.user.id, new_id, ext) #  <- Right Here!

class Cloth(models.Model):
    cloth_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
```

I'm using AWS S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want unique filename, i think you can use `uuid` for it, for example

```
import uuid
import os

def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    base_dir = 'clothes'
    user.id = str(instance.user.id)
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return os.path.join(base_dir, user_id, filename)
```

Comment: I like this idea. What if uuid.uuid4() generated previous id? Do they store previous generated id to somewhere? If not, it's just random integer, isn't it?

Comment: this is composite field based on many parameters you can read  more [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html)

Comment: Um.. exactly. I want to generate REAL unique id for image filename. :(

Comment: nvm uuid is pretty legit in generating random filename. Cool Stuff! Thanks

Comment: glad to help you)

Comment: Check this out!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469026/retrieveapiview-without-lookup-field

Answer (score 1):

Just use the filename and not the id, e.g.

```
os.path.join('clothes', instance.user.id, filename)
```

Don't worry if filename already exists, Django automatically appends random strings at the end to avoid file replacements.