# RetrieveAPIView without lookup field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

By default RetrieveAPIView or RetrieveUpdateAPIView requires `lookup_field` to retrieve Model.

However in my case, I want to retrieve my model by self.request.user.

Here is views.py example

```
class ProfileRetrieveAndUpdateProfile(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileRetrieveAndUpdateSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.all()
        logged_in_user_profile = qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return logged_in_user_profile
```

Can I use RetrieveAPIView **without lookup_field**?

Comment: where you find that `lookup_field` is required? i not found it in the docs, and it woks at my project.

Comment: this attr has default value in the `GenericAPIView` and itis used for get object.

Comment: I get this error if I don't specify `lookup_field` : Expected view ProfilePageView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

Comment: it means you just need got to the url with `pk` something `/profile/213/`

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to put extra parameter. /profile/.. Maybe it's not possible?

Comment: I'm using ListAPIView to do so. I just wanna know if I can do it with RetrieveAPIView...

Comment: I need UpdateAPIView to update it...! For bad case, in my mobile, I have to store my user id... Which is that I really want to avoid

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need override `get_object`

```
def get_object(self):
  queryset = self.get_queryset()
  obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, user=self.request.user)
  return obj
```

Comment: Check this out too! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471364/multiple-logics-in-filter

Comment: I need help on ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884850/how-to-paginate-queryset-for-serializer