# Multiple Logics in filter

Tags: django, django-models

I'm implementing ModelManger for privacy.

Basically, I want to exclude some queryset for this case

1. if post(Cloth)'s field `only_me` is `true`
2. and owner of post(Cloth) is not logged in user.

   ```
   class ClothManager(models.Manager):
       def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
           return super(ClothManager, self).filter(???)
   ```

Use Case

- returns `qs` if `only_me==false`
- returns `qs` if `only_me==true` and `user==self.request.user` (Can we call `self.request.user` in Model?)
- DO NOT return `qs` if `only_me=true` and `user is not self.request.user`

I can use `Q` if it's needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
class ClothManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, user=None, request=None, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ClothManager, self).get_queryset()
        user = request.user if not user else user
        if request:
            user = request.user if not user else user

        if user:
            qs = qs.exclude(Q(only_me=True) & ~Q(user=self.request.user))
        return qs

    def __call__(self, user=None, request=None, **kwargs):
        return self.get_queryset(user=user, request=request, **kwargs)
```

and somewhere in the code:

```
 qs = YourModel.objects(request=request)
```

Comment: Is there any other method rather than get_queryset? objects(request=request) looks ugly :(

Comment: qs = YourModel.objects.(request=request).filter(condition) . Is this possible?

Comment: yes `YourModel.objects(request=request).filter(condition) `, the main idea of the solution - you can use all standard method.

Comment: Let me try on my computer

Comment: you can call `qs = YourModel.objects(user=user)` if you have user and not have request, `if not user else user` means set value user if it not empty

Comment: i'm off for a time

Comment: What will be `HereYourCondition`? Actually I was mainly asking `hereYourCondition`

Comment: something `user_fk_field = user`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481016/how-to-find-user-queryset-matching-self-request-user

Comment: Try this one too it will be simple enough : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499573/field-name-user-username-is-not-valid-for-model-profile