# How to find User queryset matching self.request.user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How do we find User queryset matching self.request.user?

```
logged_in_user = User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
```

I wish there is much efficient way to doing this. (such as get_user_model(self.request.user)) ?

Here is my views.py

```
class ProfilePageView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfilePageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        logged_in_user = User.objects.filter(username=self.request.user.username) << right here!
        return logged_in_user

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
        return obj
```

Comment: Oh can I just use it like logged_in_user = self.request.user?

Comment: queryset not an object.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to get a queryset with just the one User instance in it, when you already have the user instance:

```
logged_in_user = self.request.user
```

Comment: Getting this error. First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'User'.

Comment: May be I should convert self.request.user to queryset..??

Comment: I don't see any `get_object_or_404` usage in your question.

Comment: Oh I was getting `queryset`. Yes it has to perform exactly User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id).

Comment: self.requset.user is object model not queryset

Answer (score 1):

may be it help you?

```
def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user
```