# Field name user_username is not valid for model Profile

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

Error Name: Field name `user_username` is not valid for model `Profile`

I'm building my Edit Profile View.

Here is my `views.py`

```
class ProfileEditAPIView(DestroyModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileEditSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        logged_in_user = User.objects.filter(username=self.request.user.username)
        return logged_in_user

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
        return obj.profile

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**I can get user_id correctly but somehow I can't access to its username field**

This is `serializers.py`

```
class ProfileEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'user_username', <<<
            'title',
            'gender',
            'birth',
            'height',
            'height_in_ft',
            'profile_img',
        )
```

`models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=155, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='u') # Recommend Factor
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='ud') # Recommend Factor
    birth = models.DateField(default='1992-07-23', blank=True, null=True) # Recommend Factor
    height = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='undefined')
    height_in_ft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True,
        blank=True)
```

Why can't we access to user's username? And how can we solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your profile model ?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar Just edited the question. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Shouldn't `user_username` be `user__username` ? Double underscore ?

Comment: I'm getting same error with it too. Field name `user__username` is not valid for model `Profile`.

Comment: Weird. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah weird !! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `username` from `User` model using this way.

```
class ProfileEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="user.username")

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'username',
            'title',
            . . . .
        )
```

Comment: Almost..!! Since it's read_only your answer doesn't count on this problem. If you check my views.py, it has UpdateModelMixin. sorry

Comment: @JohnBaek, Ideally you should not give an option to change username. but if you wnat to change, then just **remove** `read_only=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the username like the way its viewed in the model i.e user.

Change:

```
        fields = (
        'user_username', <<<
        'title',
        'gender',
        'birth',
        'height',
        'height_in_ft',
        'profile_img',
    )
```

To:

```
        fields = (
        'user', 
        'title',
        'gender',
        'birth',
        'height',
        'height_in_ft',
        'profile_img',
    )
```

But if you want it to appear as username in your json response, use:

```
class ProfileEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   username = serializers.CharField(source='user')


class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = (
        'username', <<<
        'title',
        'gender',
        'birth',
        'height',
        'height_in_ft',
        'profile_img',
    )
```