# Django DRF: ModelMixin Viewset: How to create a viewset to get user details and edit user details without passing id in url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose my user is logged in and he want to see the user details

I want to create an api end point like `/userdetails/`

Based on the user who logged in it should return back the details.

This is my serializer

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "id",
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "is_staff",
            "is_active",
            "date_joined",
            "last_login",
            "modified_date",
            "creation_date",
        ]
        read_only_fields = [
            "email",
            "is_staff",
            "is_active",
            "is_superuser",
            "date_joined",
            "last_login",
        ]
```

Now I want to create a viewset for `read and edit`

I want something like this

```
class UserDetailsViewSet(
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailsSerializer
```

and

```
router.register(r"userdetail",UserDetailsViewSet )
```

But the problem with the above is I dont want urls like
`/userdetail/<pk>` instead only `/userdetail`. Because the `<pk>` can be obtained from the `request.user`

**solution**

After checking some posts, what I want is something without `lookup_field` and later overwrite `get_object`. Something similar to [RetrieveAPIView without lookup field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469026/retrieveapiview-without-lookup-field)

**question remaining**
how to avoid `lookup_field` I tried

```
class UserDetailsViewSet(
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailsSerializer
    lookup_field = ''
```

but it give error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^userdetail/(?P<>[^/.]+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: missing group name at position 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass **UserDetailsViewSet** from **generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView**
and override **get_object**

Example:

```
class UserDetailsViewSet(
    generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView
):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailsSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=self.request.user.id)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

register the view outside the drf router.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('userdetail/', views.UserDetailsViewSet.as_view(),)
    ...
]
```